# Does under the getServerSideProps() can i used the post fetch mthod for sending request to the node js backend?

Tags: next.js

I am thinking  that my getServerSideProps is not Working

```
import profilePage from "@/components/profilecomp";
import header from "@/components/header";
import sideProfile from "@/components/sideleftnav";
import styles from '@/styles/profilepage.module.css';
import Footer from "@/components/footer";
import { findDataFromLocalStorage } from "@/alg/local";
export default function profile(data:any) {
    return (
        <>

            {header()}
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <div className={styles.sideleftnav}>
                    {sideProfile()}
                </div>

                <div className={styles.userdatacontainer}>
                    {profilePage(data)}
                </div>




            </div>



        </>
    )
}


export async function getServerSideProps(contex: any) {
    try {
        console.log( 'this')

        const pK = findDataFromLocalStorage()?.id;
        // alert(pK)
        console.log(pK, 'this')
        // console.log(pK, 'this')
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',

            body: JSON.stringify({ key: pK }), // Convert your data to JSON format
        };
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/getprofile', requestOptions);
        const data = await res.json();
        return {
            props: { data },
        };

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.error(error);
        return {
            props: {
                data: null, // Handle the error by setting data to null or an appropriate value
            },
        };
    }
}
```

I am sending post request under the getServerSideProps() to the node js backend but not Working on the there is no issue under the node server because i cheked by the help of post man i think my getServerSidePros() function is not Wokring or what?